# CustusX plugin: Where are the compiled .ui files stored and what's the naming convention?

Tags: qt, plugins

For a plugin for [CustusX](http://www.custusx.org) which realizes GUIExtenderService I want to use a Qt Designer file (.ui) to define the GUI Widget.

The CMakeLists.txt has already a section with:

```
# Qt Designer files which should be processed by Qts uic
set(PLUGIN_UI_FORMS
)
```

If I put a ui file there it is processed by the uic tool (if I supply the wrong name it failes on cmake generate). However, I cannot find it again neither in the build directory nor in the source directory.

Where are the compiled ui files placed and what's their name for inclusion?

Comment: I wanted to create a custusx tag, but I don't have enough reputation. I consider this an issue related only to this software package, so I would appreciate such a tag (this is along the lines of this [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work): adding a comment and ask for creation). It seems as well that it was the intention of authors that questions are asked here (From their [developers page](http://www.custusx.org/index.php/developers): "Post a question on stackoverflow.com/search?q=custusx, use the tag custusx")

Comment: Although you are using CustusX, your question is relatet to the use of qt+cmake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I overlooked the obvious - for completeness:

In CmakeLists.txt, add the ui file in the section for the Qt Designer files:

```
# Qt Designer files which should be processed by Qts uic
set(PLUGIN_UI_FORMS
    foo.ui
)
```

Then a file `ui_foo.h` is created in the plugin build directory (e.g. `my_custus_build_directory/source/plugins/org.custusx.myplugin/ui_foo.h`)

Comment: This location can be referred to using the cmake variable CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR. You can also use the corresponding CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR for the .ui file location.